# My customers can't afford to buy the items I'm trying to sell. What do I do?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

In my first playthrough of Recettear, I've got a bunch of great items to sell, like Parade Armor and Parade Helmets...and a bunch of customers who are too cheap to afford them. Any time I try to sell an item for over 3000 gold, it fails miserably. I've tried selling expensive items at even 70% of their actual cost and yet they're rejected time and time again. But I bought these items with my own gold at close to base price and I don't want to lose my money for nothing.

How should I react in situations like this? Should I bite the bullet and try to recoup my losses by selling at half price? Or is there a way for me to quickly attract customers who have more coins in their purses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Customers have their own budgets, which may increase over time. They'll specifically increase based on **how much they like your store**. This, in turn, is determined by how often you have successful exchanges with them, selling or buying.

As customers successfully purchase items from you or sell items to you, they will gain favor. You may have noticed that as you sell or buy items, you might get something called "Near Pin", or even "Just Bonus", which increases the amount of experience you get from the base 10 to 15 or 30 respectively. It also affects how much favor you get - you get significantly more favor when you get a Just Bonus, and still fair more favor with a Near Pin sale than if you just normally sell the item.

In general, regardless of their individual maxes, **most customers like to buy in the 100-110% range, and sell in the 60-70% range** - the exact percentage value is rolled on each transaction. If you hit the value, you get a Just Bonus. If you hit just around the value, then you'll get a Near Pin. As such, a common thing is to sell items at 104% or 105% and buy items at 65% and 66% in order to veritably guarantee a Near Pin. This doesn't really get you a lot of money, though, so this is *often best done with your cheaper items to gain favor*.

You do this because favor increases the budget they'll have. Whenever a customer hits a new budget level (and thus can spend more money), then after the successful transaction, a little Heart emote will show up. That's what you want to see, it means they'll start buying slightly more expensive stuff. So you need to start building up favor until their budgets rise. Then you can start selling your high quality goods.

Eventually it comes to the point that you regularly sell all your cheaper items with the intent of gaining favor, and only go for the full markup when selling the more expensive items to those who have the wallet for it.

---

Be on the lookout for booms, by the way. Usually you can buy an extremely cheap item for the boom, and so the number of sales you can make will *significantly* improve the customer favor and consequently the budgets they have.

Comment: I still can't believe I made it through the entire game -twice- before I realized that booms were more than just flavor text.

Comment: @GraceNote: In my experience, till the second payment, I've managed to sell for 130%-125% to most customers; 125%-120% to those that are in doubt, except I need something low for the child like 115%-110%. I'm wondering if your statement in bold is correct...

Comment: @Tom There's a difference between "What the customer *wants* to pay/get" versus "What the customer is *willing* to pay/get". The values in my bold section are only the former - the values you're thinking of are the latter. The former will get you better favor, the latter will get you better profits.

Comment: Its worth adding that each customer has their own behavior. Memorizing faces to buy/sell ranges is definitely worth your time (try pen and paper if you have a bad memory).

Comment: Little girls are the bane of my existence as a merchant. *hisss* But by the way, does failing to make a transaction reduce reputation?

Comment: @Zibbobz It's been a while, but if I recall correctly, if you fail a sale due to overcharging (too much for the value of the item, or well past the target's budget), then it does penalize your reputation. Failing to have the items for a request, though, I do not believe penalizes you. The penalty is smaller than the amount you gain from Near Pin / Just Bonus, though, so you can afford small losses here and there. Though obviously you'd want to avoid them.